# Eclipse ID license

Tags: java, eclipse

I work at a corporation.  We want to use Eclipse to create our product for java.

Do we need to buy a license?  Why would someone buy a license?

Comment: Does your company require a license for every piece of software they use? I've heard of some places that do that.

Comment: I my company required me to do that for Eclipse I would print their terms of use, sign it, and send it to legal for them to file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to purchase a license to use the Eclipse IDE.

The terms of use are here: http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl/notice.php

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is completely free, that is one of its main attractions. Generally speaking, most of what you will download from eclipse.org is free though you may want to read the license.

Some vendors, such as IBM, sell commercial versions of IDEs that are based on the Eclipse core but include a variety of proprietary plugins for things like collaboration, web development, etc. You don't need those if you want to use the standard facilities.